# Encoding Strings over Raw Sockets - Extra Characters

Tags: java, c#, xml, sockets, character-encoding

I'm troubleshooting a commercial application that is having problems reading the XML i'm sending.

My application is Java, the commercial application is written in C# .NET 4.0 on Windows. The C# application is listening on a simple TCP socket for raw XML.  I send data as bytes on the wire from a string (XML).  Both the Java and C# code is running on the same host.  Data is sent over localhost.

Every *other* message the C# application responds with an error indicating malformed XML.  Both the commercial team and I are confounded as to why.  In the debugger, and logs the XML i'm sending is valid. However, once it arrives on the C# side; a single character or two is added to the XML declaration.

What we found in the logs:

```
 Expected
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

 Observed
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-M1" ?>
 <?xml oversion="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 <?=xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

I'm sending to the C# application with something like in Java.

```
String request = "Whatever";
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(Host, Port);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()) ;
outToServer.writeBytes(request + '\n');
```

The C# Application is receiving data from the wire as follows.

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
NetworkStream networkStream = null;
byte[] array = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
string text = "";
this.lastTouched = DateTime.Now;
try
{
    networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    do
    {
        int count = networkStream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
        text += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array, 0, count);
    }
```

I have a feeling we are both making mistakes here; but it works on other systems with the same code, and I think that is a coincidence. We are simply seeing an edge-case.

Thoughts?

Comment: do you close your outputstream?

Comment: What range of characters (set of values) do you need to send? ISO-8859-1 is not a good choice with DataOutputStream.writeBytes. - And the spurious characters never appear anywhere else - only in every other XML declaration? Is the encoding flaxible so that you need the declaration? How does the receiver detect the end of one XML document - is this by the appended \n? I don't see that being done in the C# client.

Comment: The application is ensuring only valid ISO-8859-1 characters are being written, so I'm not currently worried about the whole unicode set.  Also this communicates with QuickBooks; and that is also only ISO-8859-1.  I'm going to test with the "\n" I think it is simply extra line that made it easier to observe the string on the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `DataOutputStream`, that class is used rather for serialization, you are sending a raw string as long as I understood. Try using the OutputStream directly:

```
 // for this to use the UTF-8 encoding in <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(request.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

You need to play around with the encoding you specify in `getBytes(...)` and also the encoding used in your XML file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..." ?>`

In the C# part:

Are you sure that all the characters in the string are ASCII (you don't have chars like Ñ)? it has ages since last time I wrote something in C#, but it seems you're using ASCII to decode the string, Wouldn't be more appropriate to use another encoding?

Comment: DataOutputStream.writeBytes is (according to its definition) writing bytes. It depends on the range of char values (Java's native representation) what is actually written. If the protocol requires 8859-1, String.getBytes() is risky, too.

Comment: @laune the method `writeBytes()` is not appropriate to send a java String (have a look at the internal code and you'll see why) using `getBytes(...)` is not risky as an encoding is being specified

Comment: You can write "raw" bytes to an OutputStream using ObjectOutputStream if the characters are ASCII or even contained in ISO-8859-1. Thus, a simple file written that way can be read with an InputStreamReader, setting the encoding as ISO-8859-1. - Whatever OP's problem, I don't think it's due to using DataOutputStream.writeBytes(). - I don't know what you are hinting at, - but why would this hiccup the way OP described it?

Comment: Morgano, you are correct.  This resolved the issue, why it worked in a majority of installations is beyond me.